# Algorithm for finding a Hamiltonian path in a DAG

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, path-connected

Consider a directed acyclic graph (DAG) $G$ with $n$ vertices that does not possess a Hamiltonian path.

Which algorithm can be employed to determine the minimum number of additional edges required to establish a Hamiltonian path while preserving the acyclic nature of the graph $G$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $k$ be the smallest number of directed, vertex disjoint paths in the DAG such that every vertex is adjacent to some path edge; in this context also paths with a single vertex are allowed; then the number of edges that must be added to generate a Hamilton path is $k-1$.

The calculation of such a minimal number of paths in the DAG is also efficiently possible:

- split the vertices $v$ in $v_\tau$ and $v_\sigma$, its roles as target vertex and as source vertex of directed edges.
- connect $v_\tau$ and $v_\sigma$ with the directed edge $(v_\tau,v_\sigma)$ of weight $0$
- if $u_\sigma$ comes before $v_\tau$ on some directed path in the DAG then connect $v_\tau$ with $u_\sigma$ with the directed edge $(v_\tau,u_\sigma)$ with very high weight $\mathrm{INF}$
- associate each edge with flow constraints: a capacity of $1$ for every edge of the resulting graph and a lower bound of $1$ for edges that connect splitted vertices and $0$ for all other edges
  calculate the mincost flow in $G$
- remove from the edges with nonzero flow all edges of weight $\mathrm{INF}$
- connect the resulting directed paths in the obvious way by $k-1$ directed edges

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Two points come to my mind about your answer.  1st) How can we explicitly determine the smallest number of   directed, vertex disjoint paths in the DAG in general?

Comment: 2ed) consider the DAG with $n$ nodes labeled $1,\ldots,20$ so that there is an edge form $i$ to $j$ if and only if $j\geq i+2$.   Even nodes and odd nodes form two separated paths encompassing all nodes.

Comment: But one may check that at least we need 5 edges to make a Hamiltonian path.